# Spring MVC + Velocity: proper way to bind DropDown options

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I have a form with some fields binded with spring velocity macros:

```
#springFormInput("model.email", "required email='true' maxlength='100'")
#springFormInput("model.name", "required maxlength='100'")
...
```

I want to bind a DropDown to a value, and set the OPTIONS of that DropDown to be a value on my  model, like:

```
public class MyDto {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String dropdownValue;
    private List<String> dropdownOptions;

    ...
}
```

And my view goes with:

```
#springFormInput("model.email", "required email='true' maxlength='100'")
#springFormInput("model.name", "required maxlength='100'")
#springFormSingleSelect("model.dropdownValue", "dropdownOptions", "required")
...
```

It's not working. The list comes without values.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

```
#springFormSingleSelect ($path $options $attributes)
```

- ***Drop down box of options allowing a single required value to be selected.***

The parameters:

- **`path`**: the name of the field to bind to (that is, `searchCriteria.title`).
- **`options`**: a `Map` containing all the available values that can be selected from in the input field. The keys to the map represent the values that will be `POST`ed back from the form and bound to the command object. The values belonging to the key are used as the labels to show to the user. Usually such a map is supplied as reference data by the controller. Any Map implementation can be used, depending on required behavior.
- **`attributes`**: an additional string of arbitrary tags or text to be included within the
  HTML tag itself. This string is echoed *literally* by the macro. For example, in a
  `textarea` field you may supply attributes as `'rows="5" cols="60"'` or you could pass
  style information such as `'style="border:1px solid silver"'`.

---

So, in your specific case, you have to make `dropdownOptions` a `Map`:

```
private Map<String, String> dropdownOptions;
```

Adding objects to the map like `map.put("x","y")` generates a `<option value="x">y</option>`.

And then use it in the view like:

```
#springFormSingleSelect("model.dropdownValue", $model.dropdownOptions,"required")
```

Out of curiosity, here the macro's code (the call to `.keySet()` makes a `Map` required):

```
#macro( springFormSingleSelect $path $options $attributes )
    #springBind($path)
    <select id="${status.expression}" name="${status.expression}" ${attributes}>
        #foreach($option in $options.keySet())
            <option value="${option}"
            #if("$!status.value" == "$option")
                selected="selected"
            #end>
            ${options.get($option)}</option>
        #end
    </select>
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question which I hope the answer would help you with this question you have.

```
 #set ($end = $dataItems.size() - 1)
    #foreach($i in [0..$end])
      #springFormSingleSelect( "dataItems[$i].data1" $labelKeys "")
    #end
```

[the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070210/binding-a-variable-collection-inside-a-spring-enabled-velocity-template)

Comment: That's the way to do with JSP, i wanna do it with Velocity! Thanks, but that doesn't help

Comment: I searched for you and found more information. I hope this works. give it a try.

Comment: I looked those samples before posting the question.. this is another issue!

Comment: I tried , sorry that was not what you were looking for. I'll search more and if I come across anything I'll post it for you.